# How to find why a program under Wine stopped working?

Tags: wine

I have [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) running under Wine, which I use infrequently (1 or 2 times a month). It has always worked well.

Today I noticed it wasn't working: when I ran it from a shell, it doesn't start up, I don't get any error message.

I've tried a clean install and a new `WINEPREFIX`, didn't work, and I created a new user to test, didn't work either. Other programs under Wine work.

How would I debug to find **why** it's not starting? 
I'm using `wine-4.8` in Fedora 30.

**EDIT:** as a workaround, I downgraded to `wine-4.5` and it worked. Still I'd like to understand what happened to `wine-4.8` that it doesn't work.

Comment: did wine get updated since the last time you used ltspice ?

Comment: @intika Yes, since I upgraded from Fedora 29 to 30 it went from 4.6 (where LTspice was working, IIRC) to 4.7 and then 4.8.

Comment: Can you try [`WINEDEBUG`](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debug_Channels) environment variable to get debug output in terminal.

Comment: @Biswapriyo sure, with WINEDEBUG=+all: https://pastebin.com/JhCdj5re.

Comment: I don't know about what happen in Fedora but I run that software in Arch+wine and it works fine. If you've time try to complie the latest wine git repo.

Comment: Just to come back at this: today I updated to `wine-4.9.1` now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The logs:**

Under windows i would of recommended you to check the event logs (or tools like [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html) or [that](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/my_event_viewer.html) one),
*But* with wine it's an other story, here is a quote from [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707941/where-are-wine-program-execution-logs-stored)

> The wine run logs are hidden typically, they're not stored anywhere.
>   To get the Wine logs for a specific executable, you need to run it via the terminal with the `wine` command. (Note you need the full path here, or you need to first `cd` into the directory where the .exe is stored.)

```
wine /path/to/program.exe
```

**Wine Apps DB:**

Often we find good informations about apps compatibility on their [apps data base](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2000)

**Winedbg**

[Winedbg](https://linux.die.net/man/1/winedbg) can help you out to identify the problem by debugging the application. also [here is](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_Developer%27s_Guide/Debugging_Wine) the official debugging tutorial.

**Updates**

A new version of wine may break old working applications by adding new features/changes on new version, it's not unusual to see that an application is perfectly compatible with wine v3 and not with wine v3.5

**Alternative**

If your application works only with a specific wine version you could use an additional wine installation to run that application (don't forget to separate the profile foder "~/.wine") [here is a question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245900/how-do-i-use-two-different-versions-of-wine-on-the-same-installation) for the matter

Comment: I downgraded to `wine-4.5` as a workaround and it worked. I guess I will look at PlayOnLinux as an approach to simplify this.

Comment: Yes or just install wine from source this will get it installed to /usr/local then just set a different "~/.wine" to the /usr/local version